# Vertical Align Div to Middle Beside Big Image

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

Hello Stackoverflow Forum,

I am aware that my issue is a well documented on the internet with all kinds of scenarios. I must now conclude that I don't know how to solve this complication despite all the articles and posts I red so far.

My problem is very simple. I wanna vertically align my div element content to the middle beside a big picture. It seems impossible for me, but I know there must be a simple solution. That's why I came here ;-)

I would really appreciate any kind of input that can help me accomplish my goal. Here is a link to a simple structure of the described subject:

```
Link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vLbgntyy/
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vLbgntyy/1/
```

will give you IE8 support as well.

It will keep them in one line even when the window resizes.

If you want to do something responsive that will collapse when the screen gets too small, this is not the solution for you most probably.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to support browsers older than IE10, you could do this with flex box pretty easily.

Try adding these properties to your "container" class.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Edit: I also got it working with `display: table;` https://jsfiddle.net/yovcuk4d/

Answer (score 1):

Modify your css as below it might help u check output in [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xaxaqar/edit?html,css)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

.container > img {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.container > .content {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding:150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 position:relative;
 top:150px;
 
 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      I am desperate to be aligned to the middle. Please help me, I'm just a simple paragraph.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```